Question on DC removal filter structure/equation from Coursera DSP class
I am following the DSP class on Cousera, but got confused by the DC removal filter in the video below, at 8:00 :
https://www.coursera.org/learn/dsp2/lecture/JcNy2/2-2-3-intuitive-iir-designs
Here is the filter structure, and time domain equation:

The node I annotated on the diagram doesn't seem to match $$y[n-1]$$ nor $$x[n-1]$$
How is above filter matching the time domain equation?
Shouldn't the filter structure looks like this below?

Did I miss anything?

Hi, have you tried to compare the output of your structure vs the suggested structure using paper and pen?

Have you covered the different filter topologies in class yet? Things like Direct Form I, Direct Form II, Transposed Form I, and Transposed Form II?

I haven't learned those different forms yet.

"have you tried to compare the output of your structure vs the suggested structure using paper and pen?"
I am not able to figure out what is the value for the intermidiate node

@neb see my answer on the "intermediate node".

You need to think about the Direct Form I structure in relation to the Direct Form II structure.

Work with intermediate signals!
Denote the signal coming out of the first accumulator by $u[n]$:
Then $$y[n] = u[n] - u[n-1]\tag{1}$$
And
$$u[n] = x[n] + \lambda u[n-1]$$
Substitute $u[n]$ in $(1)$:
\begin{align}
y[n] &= x[n] + \lambda u[n-1] - x[n-1] - \lambda u[n-2] \\
&= x[n] - x[n-1] + \lambda (u[n-1]-u[n-2])\\
&= x[n] - x[n-1] + \lambda y[n-1]
\end{align}

Thanks for the details proof! For a moment, I thought u[n] is unit step signal and couldn't understand why. So u[n] is just the intermediate note between 2 accumulator and before z^-1

Note that the two structures shown as diagrammed by the OP (feedforward difference followed by an accumulator) are linear structure and thus the order can be arbitrarily rearranged such that the accumulator appears first followed by the feedforward difference stage. This would have the delay elements ($z^{-1}$) facing each other such that a single delay can be used, resulting in the structure presented in the course.  (In fixed point design there are considerations of one approach over the other, but otherwise this is just the communicative law that the resulting polynomials would follow).

I see. This makes sense. So if I switch the 2 loops in my diagram, I will get the one from the instructor.

But how to prove this switching is ok? Is there a way to prove the following argument?
"are linear structure and thus the order can be arbitrarily rearranged"

Yes you can use the communicative law of mathematics as I described- write out the transfer function in the z-domain (H(z)) for the two blocks. When you cascade such systems the result is the product of the transfer functions. You get the same result for the combined transfer function independent of order.
